# Bug on Emulator - Android Studio Chipmunk 2021.2.1 Canary 7

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, ide

Virtual emulator by default is now dock with the IDE itself instead of floating window, thus I changed its **View Mode** to Float and later Window. Now it seems scrolling no longer works properly on both setup and I believe there is a bug going on here based on the experience I am getting. Whenever I scroll up or down using a mouse, the virtual device disappear and running it again will prompt the user that the device is already running. The question is where did the emulator go? I cannot see it on any tab either.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Having the same issue...Have you found any solutions?

Comment: @FebinMathew
File->Settings->Tools->Emulator, and uncheck Launch in a tool window Then they will open in their own stand alone windows again.

You also might need to update Android Emulator at SDK manager to fix some issue with emulator on SDK 31

Comment: Thanks, man. You saved me. Just curious why big brains at Google can't find this bug...

Answer (score 3):

The emulator tool is located on the right side of the IDE. When the emulator tool is closed, the emulator is still running so you need to just click on "Emulator" on the right side of the IDE. However, as you mentioned, it is buggy and sometimes you have to stop the emulator and rerun to get it to display again.

However, to make things easier, you can launch the emulators in their own separate windows. It seems to be more user friendly.

To get the emulator to launch in their own windows, you have to disable the the "Launch in a tool window" setting. Here are the instructions to disable it.

**Android Studio on Mac:**
Go to Android Studio->Preferences->Tools->Emulator and then uncheck "Launch in a tool window"

**Android Studio on Windows:**
Go to File->Settings->Tools->Emulator and then uncheck "Launch in a tool window"

Now your emulators will open in their own windows and you can even open multiple emulators and view them side-by-side if you wish. With the Emulator tool, it was impossible to view multiple emulators side-by-side. Instead, you had to switch emulator tabs.

Comment: `uncheck "Launch in a tool window"` is working and fixed. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please press long click on power button of the emulator and then press power off.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToKWj.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

make sure your source code app there is no error compiling, then just click button Run your code (not button run / play emulator), when your app delivered to emulator, your emulator appear back again

[button run app on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bYKL.png)